# Vote I want the rectangular less wide

Tags: html, css, web-frontend

Please check the below link to check the code in HTML and CSS and check the result. Please, I need the rectangular in the result to be less wide.

https://jsfiddle.net/Ahmed_abdelmeguid/6L8vbutw/5/
[enter image description here][1]

this is CSS code

```
.tictac_3 > ul {
    width: 50%;
    height: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;}
  
  .tictac_3 > li  {
    width: 30%;
    height: 30px;
     font-size: 30px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color:lightblue;
    margin: 5px;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
   float: left;
  }
```

and below the HTML code

```
<ul class="tictac_3"> 
                                        <li class=".tictac_3">X
                                        <li class=".tictac_3">
                                        <li class=".tictac_3">O
                                
                                        <li class=".tictac_3">
                                        <li class=".tictac_3">X
                                        <li class=".tictac_3">O
                                
                                        <li class=".tictac_3">X
                                        <li class=".tictac_3">O
                                        <li class=".tictac_3">
                                        </ul>
```

you can check the code and the result that I want to modify it in the below link That I provided it in the start of my question
https://jsfiddle.net/Ahmed_abdelmeguid/6L8vbutw/5/

Answer (score 0):

**Problems**

> *"Please, I need the rectangular in the result to be less wide"*

OK, there are some problems with OP code that are at fundamental level:

- Every `<li>` end tag `</li>` is missing
- The selector: `.tictac_3 > ul` does not exist
- `height: 20px` is assigned to the previously mentioned selector. If it referenced the `<ul>` as was intended, it would make very little sense since all of it's `<li>` are `height: 30px`

**Changes**

- All of the classes on the `<li>` is removed, a single class on the `<ul>` is sufficient.
- Added `max-width: 12rem;` to the `<ul>`

*Each `<li>`*

- Changed `height` from an absolute value `30px` to a relative value `2rem`.
- Changed `font-size` exactly as `height` was changed.
- Decreased the `margin` from `5px` to `1px`
- Added a little `padding-bottom: 0.25em`

```css
.tictac {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 50%;
  max-width: 12rem;
  list-style: none;
}

.tictac li {
  width: 30%;
  height: 2rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 0.1em;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tictac">
  <li>X</li>
  <li></li>
  <li>O</li>

  <li></li>
  <li>X</li>
  <li>O</li>

  <li>X</li>
  <li>O</li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: End `</li>` tags can be omitted according to the [HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-li-element).

Comment: Like a `<td>` I know. That applies to `<li>`  (and `<td>`) that are followed by another `<li>`  and the last `<li>` was that way as well. Besides, markup like that is sloppy and novices shouldn't develop bad habits.

Comment: The last can be that way as well.

Comment: @zer00ne your notes and modifications are very professional …you are genius Thanks a lot